# Matter.js: how to draw an ellipse?

Tags: matter.js

I am new to Matter.js.  It is powerful, but surprisingly I found that it does not have a native method to draw an ellipse.

If I want to draw an ellipse, what can I do?  Thanks

Comment: Matter.js does have a stripped down, proof-of-concept rendering engine for convenience, but it's primarily a physics engine. I'd run MJS headlessly and use any other library for the graphics. Representing the ellipse would be domain-specific, but you can use any set of x/y points or an SVG.

Comment: Thank you ggorlen.  I'll do further study on this direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an ellipse with MJS by creating an array of vertices, and then use **fromVertices()** to build your ellipse.

You can do something like this:

```
// create an array of vertices for an ellipse
let ellipseVerticesArray = [];

let ellipseFlatness = 0.5;
let ellipseVertices = 50;
let ellipseSize = 80;

for (let i = 0; i < ellipseVertices; i++) {
    let x = ellipseSize * Math.cos(i);
    let y = ellipseFlatness * ellipseSize * Math.sin(i);
    ellipseVerticesArray.push({ x: x, y: y });
}

// add one ellipse
let ellipse = Bodies.fromVertices(100, 100, ellipseVerticesArray, 5);
Composite.add(engine.world, ellipse);
```